# WinApi Commctrl trackbar identifier undeclared

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gcc, trackbar

I'm trying to handle a trackbar notification, but for some reason my GCC compiler complains that the `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` identifier is undeclared.

I have included the header,

```
#include <commctrl.h>
```

and initialised the controls,

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;  
icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
```

I have also tried `ICC_BAR_CLASSES` and a few others instead of the win95 one.

Also I'm compiling via bat file including this command

```
gcc foodplaner.o resources.o sqlite3.o -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -o foodplaner.exe
```

Creating the trackbar was no problem, it shows up and can be controlled.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760172.aspx) is available in Windows Vista and above. To use it you have to set `_WIN32_WINNT` to the minimum supported version of your application prior to including any header files. This can be done in code

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600  // Windows Vista
```

or on your compiler's command line (`-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600`). The latter is recommended to prevent introducing any mismatches. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for details.